# Omnisharp not showing custom namespaces

Tags: c#, omnisharp

I am trying to reference a custom namespace (a non-NET namespace) for the Unity editor. However, the syntax highlighting is different from .NET namespaces and the classes inside the Unity namespace aren't shown in the intellisense. Oddly enough, a namespace which Omnisharp doesn't recognize also doesn't throw an error.

[image]

Any help is appreciated :>

Answer (score 0):

If you:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Go to Edit < Preferences < External Tools in unity
3. In External Tools uncheck all the boxes under 'Generate .csproj files for:'
4. Press regenerate project files

Should help reset your intellisense

Comment: Sorry for late response. Regenerating project files with no boxes selected didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you try it with the boxes ticked?

Comment: Yes, trying with the boxes ticked also doesn't fix it.